# XSLT -> Not getting blanks between attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

Since yesterday, I am experimenting with XSLT, and after a lot of struggle, I could make my assignment work. This consists on taking some elements that are under an "ATTRIBUTE" node, and converting themselves into attributes of the parent element (which by the way can have different names). This is an example of what I need to do:

From here ->

```
<INVENTORY>
  <ITEM>
    <ATTRIBUTES>
      <SERIALNUMBER>something1</SERIALNUMBER>
      <LOCATION>something2</LOCATION>
      <BARCODE>something3</BARCODE>
    </ATTRIBUTES>
  Some Item Value
  </ITEM>
</INVENTORY>
```

To here ->

```
<INVENTORY>
    <ITEM SERIALNUMBER="something1" LOCATION="something2" BARCODE="something3">
    SomeItemValue
    </ITEM>
</INVENTORY>
```

However, and strange as it seems, I'm getting the attributes in the parent node, but without any separation nor blank spaces. I tried several, several things, but none seemed to work.

This is the XSLT template that I'm using to make the transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output encoding="us-ascii"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="ATTRIBUTES">

                <xsl:for-each select="ATTRIBUTES/*">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" separator=" ">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ATTRIBUTES">
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output that I'm getting is the following:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="us-ascii"?><INVENTORY><ITEMSERIALNUMBER="something1"LOCATION="something2"BARCODE="something3">SomeItemValue</ITEM></INVENTORY>
```

However, if a try to place a `<xml:text> </xml:text>` inside the `xsl:for-each`, I instantly stop seeing the attributes, instead of getting the whitespaces.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me in MS Visual Studio 2013 even with not valid attribute separator in  xslt template.

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output encoding="us-ascii" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="ATTRIBUTES">

        <xsl:for-each select="ATTRIBUTES/*">
          <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="ATTRIBUTES">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Changed:

```
<xsl:output encoding="us-ascii" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
```

Comment: Thanks Jaroslav. In fact, I rechecked all the code, and nothing turned out to be wrong with the transformation. The blanks were being stripped by some other process. Thanks for the help